# are external javascript files loaded sequentially or parallel?

Tags: javascript

if i have multiple script tags in my page like:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/globals.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

can i rely on the fact that code from the previous ones is already available when the latter ones are loaded?

Comment: It seems worth mentioning, on top of the correct answers below, that a script can "break" the execution order by introducing asynchronous code. For example, if the first of your scripts contained a line `setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 0);`, that alert would appear after the other scripts have been loaded. In fact, after the whole HTML has been loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, scripts are downloaded sequentially (see [this page](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#PutStylesBeforeScripts)):

> Because JavaScript code can alter the content and layout of a web
>   page, the browser delays rendering any content that follows a script
>   tag until that script has been downloaded, parsed and executed.
>   However, more importantly for round-trip times, many browsers block
>   the *downloading* of resources [such as stylesheets, images, and other scripts]
>   referenced in the document after scripts until those scripts are
>   downloaded and executed.

Comment: "many browsers block the downloading of resources until after the script is executed": I think many recent browsers do pre-fetch other resources, though (assuming that regardless of the outcome of the script, they will eventually be needed).

Answer (score 10):

They may be loaded (via the network) in parallel, but they are evaluated in sequence.

So yes, you can rely on the order.

Answer (score 8):

Short: Yes:

Without specifying `defer` or `async` properties within the script tag, the spec says, that a browser has to sequentially (sync) load those files.

In other words, a plain script tag which a browser finds needs to get

- loaded
- executed
- (block any other render/execution process while doing the above)

While a "modern" browser probably still trys to optimize that process, those steps need to be applied (at least, process-like). That is the reason why you should place script tags without further specification always at the bottom of your `<body>` tag. Even the DOM render process stops while loading/executing scripts.

To avoid that, you can specify a `defer` or `async` (HTML5 only) property in those script tags, like

```
<script defer src="/foo/bar.js"></script>
```

that tells the browser it is a script that meant to be executed after the document has been parsed.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script

Answer (score 4):

They are loaded in parallel but they run only once every file have been loaded.
So the answer is yes, you can rely on the fact.