# How can I reduce the load time of my javascripts?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code on my page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/common/layout/addAccessControls.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/common/layout/addAjaxControls.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/common/layout/addBodyControls.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/common/layout/addContentControls.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/common/layout/addThemeControls.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/common/layout/hashClick.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/common/layout/setSideBar.js"></script>
```

Is it correct that all the scripts will load one after another? If so is there a way I can make more than one load at once?

Just to clarify the question a bit. I can minify these and concat and maybe they're already mimified and concated :-)  What I am intersted to find out is the load process given these exact files. Is it one file after the other. Does the browswer do anything to parallel load. Thanks

Comment: you can use minify javascript for that it compacting JavaScript code can save many bytes of data and speed up downloading, parsing, and execution time.

Comment: I know I can use minify but I guess that wasn't the question :-(

Comment: I'd also suggest placing as many as possible to load at the end of the page, so the page's content can load & display before those requests occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first problem is that the scripts are loaded one after the other.
Second problem is the number of requests. The more requests, the longer it takes.

Most simple approach would be to concat the files server-side into one single `.js` file so that you only have one request left. This will speed up things.

If you additionally minify the scripts, this will speed up things, too.

Depending on what framework you use server-side there are various solutions on how to do this. E.g., for Node.js you can use [Piler](https://github.com/epeli/piler) to do this at runtime.

Or, of course, you can always do this manually, respectively via a build job.

PS: And, of course, you can use other mechanisms to load scripts files, such as dynamically adding script tags which will allow you to parallelize loading. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristoffer/archive/2006/12/22/loading-javascript-files-in-parallel.aspx for details.

Comment: Hi Golo, I know there are lots of things like concat and minify but my question was just concerning loading in parallel or serial. Thanks. Sam.

Comment: Hello Golo. I will check the link. That might be the information I was looking for. Sorry if I confused by not being clear with the question.

Comment: Golo - quick question. If I look in the network tab of my browser I thought I saw scripts being downloaded at the same time. How does that explain what you said when you said "loaded one after the other"?

Comment: Well, the answer may be a little longer, but it has been discussed before ;-). So instead of rewriting it, let me point you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165103/are-external-javascript-files-loaded-sequentially-or-parallel ... I think this should answer it :-).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `async` command (HTML5):

```
<script async src="slow.js"></script>
```

Dynamic scripts load:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.async = false;
script.src = url;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

[HTML5 Async Scripts](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/AsyncScripts/Default.html)

Comment: Thanks - I will read up on this. Never heard about this before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will be **loaded and executed** one after the other. And you can't change that.

But if you're concerned about performances you may be happy to learn that the **download** process is different and may be parallelized by the browser.

You can see it in Chrome by opening [the network tab of the Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network).

If you want to reduce the total time, the best solution is to concatenate all the files in one (and minify them if possible but the important operation is the concatenation).

Comment: Can you explain more. You said "they will be loaded one after the other" and then said "the download process is different". I assume here that these files are not cached any place.

Comment: A browser can execute a few requests in parallel (usually 4). As you can see using the network panel and its timeline, you'll have more than one download at the same time. But the scripts will be loaded and executed one at a time in the order you specify.

Comment: Okay I think I see what you are saying. So even if the last script has downloaded first it will not be execute until the script before it? is that correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate and minify them with tools like [this](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/19/tools-for-concatenating-and-minifying-css-and-javascript-files-in-different-development-environments/). If you have a Mac there is even an awesome app that automates this process called [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/)

Comment: Hello Miha. I know I can minify but that wasn't the question. Thanks :-) Sam

Comment: Well it kinda was because that is how you "reduce the load time of my javascripts" - concatenate info one file (or maybe more if you share some of them over several sites) and then minify :)

Answer (score 1):

This is script blocking. Its a browser feature. Different browsers download different number of files in parallel. Scripts will be loaded and executed after each other. You can read these articles by Steve Souders and Nicolas Zakas. This could help you.

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser and the number of other files being downloaded (images, for example), you may have several JavaScript files being downloaded simultaneously by the order you put them.

You can see this happening by using Firebug or Chrome's developer tools. You'll notice that your browser will always load more than one file but the maximum number of simultaneous downloads varies on the browser and version being used.

Comment: some people here are saying loaded one after the other and you are saying (plus I believe I saw this) that they are loaded in parallel sometimes. Can you clarify a bit. If they are loaded in parallel can the last one possibly finish before the first ?

Comment: That actually depends on the size of the files and the connection speed to the server where they are being hosted.

Downloads are made in parallel by the order you place them in your web page but you can have later files finishing their download before the first ones.

There's no way you can assure with 100% accuracy what's the exact order by which files will be loaded, although you can make an estimation.

Comment: Here's an hypothetical scenario where you are using 3 JS files by this order:
- framework.js (300Kb)
- core.js (10Kb)
- something_else.js (30Kb)

Now let's imagine your browser downloads 2 files in parallel. You'll get framework.js and core.js to download simultaneously. core.js would probably finish very fast and your browser would keep downloading framework.js and start something_else.js. Since something_else.js is also a small file, chances are your browser would finish downloading it before finishing framework.js.

Answer (score 0):

If your questions are related to the title (*How can I reduce the load time of my javascripts?*) a good approach is to

- review the code, removing and optimizing where necessary
- concatenate all files (in the order of loading)
- minify the code
- serve the single file with gzip compression
- make use of caching to avoid unnecessary requests

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser, different amounts of files will be loaded in parallel. They should be executed in parallel, but for the best results attach an event handler to the page like `onload`.

Concatenating your files will improve load times if they don't change by reducing the server round trip. You can also try using a cache manifest or loading tertiary scripts lazily with AJAX.

Comment: What do you mean by "attach an event handler to onload". What will that do? thanks.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('onload', functionToCallOnLoad)` will fire when the page has loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this techniques, whichever is suitable with your existing code...

```
1. Use minify version of JS code
2. Add only one external JS file (copy all content to one)
3. Use cookie less domain
```

Answer (score 0):

You could merge files when pushing them to production in order to get a single file [and minimify them]...
This way you will save requests hand checks and all steps in between ...