# Is it possible to load a script only after a script is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load Google's maps API js files. They are loaded at the end of the page. Besides, I want to load a js file that are using Google's js files. What I want to do is to load this js file after Google's files are loaded. How can I do that?

```
<script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/7a/main.js"></script>
```

This is the main.js file. I want to load another file just after this js. How can I do that?

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Comment: Put an onload event on that script block and then load your JS dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Scripts are, by default, executed sequentially, so if you do:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=..."></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

then "myscript.js" will be loaded after Google Maps script has been loaded. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165146/782609) for some more detail.

For simple use cases, this will be enough. If you want to have a bit more control and/or your app is large, take a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: I load the google js files asynchronously. That's why I cannot do that.

Comment: Actually, the code you pasted loads it sequentially. You'd need a `defer` keyboard, or some JS solution, to load it asynchronously. Anyway, have a look at RequireJS or similar tool in that case.

Comment: Could also give the `<script>` an id then bind it its `load` event.

Comment: Oh, I also modified my answer to be a bit more accurate - scripts might be loaded in parallel, but will be executed sequentially. Not a big difference in your case, but technically more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Requirejs should solve your problem. Every time you need a certain dependency, you would call `require('dependency');` and requirejs should fetch it, if it hasn't been downloaded already.

Comment: though i agree requirejs is great, it can be a bit of a sledgehammer for something like this. (Would require a lot of reworking to existing modules just get the benefit of a post-load include).

Comment: Just something to consider, even though it is quite a hassle to implement, it is also quite a hassle to reinvent requireJS if you really need it :)