# Does linking to JQuery CDN slow my site down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A total newbie. This seems like a basic question, but one that I can't find the answer to:

I have a few lines of JQuery to show and hide a responsive menu on half-a-dozen pages. I understand I need to "link" to the JQ library:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Will this slow my site down? Will a visitor have to download the whole JQ library for my two lines of code to work? if this is the case I might revert back to Javascript.

Comment: this may slow down website. Its better to have local copy on your server.

Comment: @T.Bhamare: It's ***much*** more complicated than that, and probably faster at least as often as slower than a local copy.

Comment: Initially it might be slow, but very unlikely since there's a very good chance that the user has the file already cached.

Comment: If the link is a CDN then its good to have a CDN reference. Else keep the file in local directory and get its path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you think is a site slowdown. Are some miliseconds a huge slowdown?

You can speed up the process slightly by having the jQuery library on your own server (eliminates the need for extra request to the google CDN => saves time). Another thing to speed up the process would be to use the SLIM and minified CDN versions of jQuery.

Now if you have only 2 lines of code, there might not be a particular need to just include jQuery for that (again think longterm), but think if in the future you would use jQuery for more things.

In the end the including of just jQuery will not slow down your response times that much (max of a couple of miliseconds).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Loading a script file is never free, so you have to decide whether it's worth it for the functionality provided.

Once you've decided to do it (if you do), the question is whether to use a CDN or host it locally.

Pros of a CDN:

- It may already be in browser cache because the same file is used elsewhere.
- CDNs use edge-casting, highly-optimized servers and server configurations, etc. to make delivery *as fast as possible*. While it may be possible for you to have a server that's just as fast, it's quite likely that you don't.

Const of a CDN:

- If the CDN is down, the link doesn't work even though *your* site is up and running.
- It's not under your control.

Comment: I know that it is not the question, but you can always add an onerror handler to avoid problem if server is down : `<script onerror="this.src='local_url'" src="http://down_url" />
</script>`

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes. There are certain conditions which can affect the download speed, like content blocking, cache and async.

We can caluculate how long it will take to download a file if we know the internet connection speed and the file size.

That minified jquery CDN file is 84.8 KB.

And the [average global internet connection](https://www.statista.com/statistics/204952/average-internet-connection-speed-by-country/) speed is around 7.2 Mbps.

So...

It will take about **78.45 ms** to download a file of that size.

Comment: But that's without the handshake procedure, isn't it?

Comment: don't think so, i'm quite sure anything you include in a html page will be downloaded in one way or another to greater or lesser degrees.

Comment: Actually, I can see from traffic data that it is. My 'isn't it?' was a polite form.

Comment: Well it depends on how the jquery is used on your html page. For example if you have visual content that relies on jquery for rendering then you will have to wait to download it first rather than after. See this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165103/are-external-javascript-files-loaded-sequentially-or-parallel

Comment: It is clear you do not know what is meant with the handshake procedure. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380513(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: I assumed by handshake procedure you just meant the http handshake. It's worth being more specific. Since you mean tls/ssl would you care to elaborate how that is relevant here or why it changes anything?

Comment: Because it takes time. And all handshake procedures do.

Comment: "Because it takes time." 

eh?? That doesn't answer my question. So are you saying that with ssl/tls, the client will not have to download external resources when loading a html page that requires them?

Comment: No, you said that it would take 78.54 ms. I suggested that that was without the time needed for the handshake procedure(s). You didn't agree with that.

Comment: gotcha, now i see what you're saying. My bad. Yes, that would be without the handshakes then. It would be interesting to know what the average handshake time takes for different types of protocols... So that you could get a better estimate, but i can't imagine it will make that much of a difference.

Comment: Glad that we got it sorted out with respect to the principle. But Firefox shows the procedures it goes through when downloading the necessary files for a web page, in the left lower corner, real-time. And it frequently hangs for a short while on a handshake procedure. Which is not due to Firefox, because especially Quantum is the fastest of all browsers.

Comment: That's cool. Chrome has something similar too. The handshake time would be subject to the same principle. For instance with ssl, apparently the average size of a handshake is around 2kb, and the maximum supported size of ssl (excluding the header) is 16kb.

Answer (score 0):

The CDN network will not slow down your webpage since you are trying to get the minified file. Even if you use the offline file, it will still take some time to load from the storage. Since you are developing a web site/web application, your app should be connected to network. If you are not showing any jquery content when the page first loads, you can make it to load in the background by  adding `async` attribute to the `script` tag.

You can check how much time this file takes to load by going to (in Chrome)

**developer console -> Network**.

It will show list of requests and its time to finish. Different filters are also available. So select **All** to see all network connections and time for finishing the request.